# searchkick 400 [searchkick_search] not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, searchkick

Someone is having this kind of problem with searchkick?
i did something wrong?
someone can spare a hint?

thank's

**controller:**

```
@products = Product.search(params[:query], page: params[:page])
```

**model:**

```
after_touch :reindex

 searchkick mappings: {
    product: {
      properties: {
        name: {type: "string", analyzer: "keyword"}
      }
    }
  }
   def search_data
    as_json only: [:name, :price]
    # or equivalently
    {
      name: name,
      price: price
    }
   end
```

> [400]
>   {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_parsing_exception","reason":"[match]
>   analyzer [searchkick_search] not
>   found","index":"products_development_20151125203817235","line":1,"col":89}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all
>   shards
>   failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"products_development_20151125203817235","node":"f2jvKNboRcGf0NF11yEqyw","reason":{"type":"query_parsing_exception","reason":"[match]
>   analyzer [searchkick_search] not
>   found","index":"products_development_20151125203817235","line":1,"col":89}}]},"status":400}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `merge_mappings` variable to true

```
after_touch :reindex

 searchkick merge_mappings: true, mappings: {
    product: {
      properties: {
        name: {type: "string", analyzer: "keyword"}
      }
    }
  }
   def search_data
    as_json only: [:name, :price]
    # or equivalently
    {
      name: name,
      price: price
    }
   end
```

Then run `rake searchkick:reindex:all` or `Model.reindex`

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: In order to be able to use searchkick's search features